# Programming using stm32l discovery board

Tags: stm32

I need to program an external Customized board which contains stm32l476 micro controller. It does have swd connectors. Can we use an stm32l discovery board as a st-link for programming my board?

Comment: Consult the manual/datasheet of your discovery board to see whether it has external SWD pins. It will tell you the answer.

Comment: What exact Discovery board do you have? Certain Discovery boards can be configured such that the included ST-Link can be used to program another board, while others only support the opposite case - namely disabling the included ST-Link such that the main chip can be programmed using an external ST-Link.

Comment: I own a stm32l476 discovery kit. It does have swd pins on it. But, there is no mention about using it as a programmer.

Comment: You're lucky. It's possible. See the [user manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00172179-discovery-kit-with-stm32l476vg-mcu-stmicroelectronics.pdf), chapter 10.1.4 *Using ST-LINK/V2-1 to program/debug an external STM32 application board*.